# how to set one field in a table equal to another field in a table in access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with two fields, IDCopy and ID. I want to copy the value of ID into IDCopy because ID is a number field and I need a second copy of this field as a text field.

I am used to doing things like this on sql server

```
UPDATE table SET table.IDCopy= table.ID;
```

But when I try to run that query in access it asks me for the parameter value of ID. What is the syntax for setting one column in a table to another column in Access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  can use `CStr()` to cast the `ID` number to text.  This should work when `IDCopy` is text and `ID` is numeric.

```sql
UPDATE [table] SET IDCopy = CStr(ID);
```

I bracketed the table name because `table` is a reserved word.

If Access still thinks `ID` is a parameter with this query, then `[table]` does not include a field named `ID`.